# Scrolling shapes in a panel

Tags: c#, winforms, vertical-scrolling

I'm working on a program which draws shapes on a panel. I added a vertical scroll bar to the panel but when scrolling the panel, the shapes stays where they are and don't scroll. How can I make these shapes scroll?
 I'm using this code in the paint handler to update these shapes:

```
e.Graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.Red, selectedRect);
```

Comment: can you show the way you draw those shapes? I guess you draw by cordinates and you repaint on scroll at the same position of before. Cannot say anything more with no details.

Comment: @Davide Exactly. Their positions are fixed and the paint updates them using the same position.

Answer (score 0):

on scrolling you should take care of the actual scroll position of the panel and consider this offset when painting your shapes again.

there are examples like this online (not exactly your case but could help to identify the problem):

```
private int count; 
private ArrayList arrayctl = new ArrayList();

private void button1_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e) 
{ 
    TextBox newtxt = new TextBox(); 
    newtxt.Text = count.ToString(); 
    count++; arrayctl.Add(newtxt); 
    DrawControls(); 
} 

private void DrawControls() 
{ 
    System.Drawing.Point CurrentPoint; CurrentPoint = panel1.AutoScrollPosition; 
    int i = 0; 
    panel1.Controls.Clear(); 
    panel1.SuspendLayout(); 
    foreach (TextBox txt in arrayctl) 
    {
     panel1.Controls.Add(txt); 
        txt.Width = panel1.ClientRectangle.Width; 
        txt.Top = i; i += txt.Height; 
    } 
    panel1.ResumeLayout(); 
    panel1.AutoScrollPosition = new Point(Math.Abs(panel1.AutoScrollPosition.X), Math.Abs(CurrentPoint.Y)); 
}
```

I have also found this here in SO: [Control position inside Windows.Forms.Panel with autoscroll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6314695/control-position-inside-windows-forms-panel-with-autoscroll)

Answer (score 0):

Don't add a VerticalScrollBar to the panel.  The Panel already handles scrolling itself when you set the `AutoScrollMinSize` property:

```
Rectangle selectedRect = new Rectangle(16, 16, 64, 28);

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  panel1.AutoScrollMinSize = new Size(panel1.ClientRectangle.Width - SystemInformation.VerticalScrollBarWidth, 1200);
}

private void panel1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
  e.Graphics.TranslateTransform(panel1.AutoScrollPosition.X, panel1.AutoScrollPosition.Y);
  e.Graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.Red, selectedRect);
}

private void panel1_Scroll(object sender, ScrollEventArgs e)
{
  panel1.Invalidate();
}
```